# How to place a div at the bottom of another div without know the parent's div height

Tags: javascript, css, html, height

I have had some problems to resolve this situation.

I have a div "header" with no set height because could have a variable value depending on browser.
Inside her I have two more divs and I want to place one div exacly at the bottom of the another but I never know height "header" height. I tried to define a height for div "header" but sometimes it fails.

Comment: You use female divs? *Mistake #1*

Comment: `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute` in combination with a positioning context on the parent, for example:

```
<header>
    Ohai
    <div>
        Noes!
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    position:relative;
    height:25%;
    background:#eee;
}
div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    width:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

The header's size is unknown, since it's based on the viewport height, and the div is locked to its bottom with the combination of `position:absolute` and `bottom:0`. The header needs the `position:relative` to designate it a positioning context used by absolutely positioned child elements.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/H4VDp/).

Answer (score 0):

just use `clear:both` for the second div at bottom ,and set the height of the header as `height:auto`

Sample:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="first">
      first
    </div>

    <div id="second">
    second
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{height:auto}
#first{}
#second{clear:both}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/X9XjQ/1/)

Comment: Try giving your header div a height and see where your child divs end up.

Comment: @j08691: i have a small update,removed the float:left,...but i dont find any problem with your case,check my demo now

Comment: Here's your code with the header given a height: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/X9XjQ/2/

Comment: @j08691: it will never fail,look http://jsfiddle.net/X9XjQ/3/,he just wants to place one div exacly at the bottom of the another

Comment: @j08691 just wants to place one div exacly at the bottom of the another

Comment: @j08691:if he uses height:auto for the header,it will be the best,only  needs to give heights to first and second div..!!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to set `position:relative` on the header div, and `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` on the child div you want to sit on the bottom of the header.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x8z57/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="header">

            <h2>Some title..</h2>   


            <div class="right">          
                <p style="color: black;display: inline">
                    Some data.....
                </p>                
            </div>


            <div class="left">              
                <form action="#" >
                    <input type="text" placeholder="put here..." required="required">
                    <button type="submit">Validar</button>
                </form>  
            </div>


        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{position: relative;height: 150px; border:1px solid black}
.right{right: 0; bottom: 0; top:auto; position: absolute}
.left {left: 0; bottom: 0; top:auto; position: absolute}
```

This work just fine in Chrome and Firefox but is not working in IE.
The div which have the left css is not being placed at the bottom of the "header".

Answer (score -1):

```
<div>
    <div>
        div1
    </div>
    <div>
        div2
    </div>
</div>
```